# useRef react hook to extract list elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-ref

Hi I'm rewriting `document.querySelectorAll` into `useRef` to extract list elements and

I want to get `[li,li,li]` using ref.

```
return (
    <div id="container">
      <ul ref={ref1}>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <div ref={ref2} />
        <div ref={ref3} />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Using `const liEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul li")];`

returns `[li, li, li]` (which is what I want to get with useRef)

However when I rewrite with useRef ref={ref1}
and

```
 const ref1 = useRef(null);
 useEffect(() => {
    if (ref1.current === null) return;
    else {
      console.log("ref1.current", ref1.current);
    }
  }, [ref1.current]);
```

I'm getting full of `<ul>...</ul>` part and not array of lists `[li,li,li]`

Is there any way to extract the list array?

Comment: Try `ref1.current.children` instead. (or `ref.current.querySelectorAll('li')`)

Comment: I don't see anything actually trying to use `ref1.current`'s children. Note also that elements have `querySelectorAll` as well, so you can use it on `ref1.current` to replicate what you're getting with your document-based qSA.

Comment: Semantically, having `div` elements as direct children of a `ul` is invalid so this "check if it's a `li`" shouldn't be an issue in the first place. Honestly you should refactor your HTML to take the divs out of the `ul` so you don't have to check if something's a `li` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your ref is on the `<ul>` element, which is why it returns `<ul>`. If you want to create a list of the children elements within, you could do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (ref1.current) {
      const list = Object.entries(ref1.current.children).map(([index, child]) => {
        return child
      })
      // do something with list
    }
  }, [ref1]);
```

Also you shouldn't have type  as a child element of